# Demidovich problems 556 and 557

Tags: calculus, limits

Exist two problems:

$$
№556: \lim_{x\rightarrow0}(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{3})^{\frac{1}{x}};
$$
$$
№557: \lim_{x\rightarrow0}(\frac{a^{x+1}+b^{x+1}+c^{x+1}}{a+b+c})^{\frac{1}{x}}
$$

And $(a>0,b>0,c>0)$. I sure that have one solution for both.

Comment: This looks like the - limit definition of e - where e is a number between 2 and 3.  See http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma122/elimit.pdf

Comment: What did you try by yourself already ?

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule or series will work. Take the logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{3})^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
On substituting $x=0$, the limit is of the form $1^{\infty}$.
Hence,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{3})^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{3}-1\right)\frac1x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{\left(\frac{a^x-1}{x}+\frac{b^x-1}{x}+\frac{c^x-1}{x}\right)\frac13}=e^{\frac{\ln a+\ln b+\ln c}3}=e^{\ln ({abc}^{\frac13})}=(abc)^{\frac13}$$

Similarly, the other problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Write $\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{3}\right)^{1/x}=e^{\frac{\ln\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{3}}{x}}$ and apply the L'hospital rule.